# Save data to firebase realtime from a picker's item which data is retrieved from firebase also, in xamarin form

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, picker

My problem is how to save data from picker's value to firebase realtime. Anyway, Im super beginner to xamarin and so far I cant find any solution to my problem.

This is what I tried.
//my model
`

```
public int DeliveryPrice { get; set; }
    public int PickUp_Price { get; set; }
    public string gallonType { get; set; }
    public string refillName { get; set; }

    public int refill_id { get; set; }
    public string waterType { get; set; }
```

`

//Code how I get the data from my firebase realtime db
`

```
public async Task<List<PRODUCT_REFILL>> GetAllProductRefill()
    {
        return 
            (await firebaseClient.Child
            (nameof(PRODUCT_REFILL))
            .OnceAsync<PRODUCT_REFILL>()).Select(item => new PRODUCT_REFILL
        {
            
          DeliveryPrice=item.Object.DeliveryPrice,
          PickUp_Price=item.Object.PickUp_Price,
          gallonType=item.Object.gallonType,
          refillName=item.Object.refillName,
          waterType=item.Object.waterType,
          refill_id=item.Object.refill_id

        }).ToList();
    }
```

`

//my picker design UI
`

```
<Picker x:Name="Picker_ProductType"                                        
       ItemsSource="{Binding refillName}"
      ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding refillName}">
     <Picker.Items  >                                                       <x:String >
                                                                           </x:String> 
<x:String>
                                                                          </x:String>
</Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

`

//my codebehind
`

```
Product_RefillRepo productrefill = new Product_RefillRepo();
async protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
     var productRefill = await productrefill.GetAllProductRefill();
        Picker_ProductType.ItemsSource = productRefill;

     }
```

`

//in my order button, which is also inside in code behind.cs
`string orderProductType = Picker_ProductType.SelectedItem.ToString();`
Then if click the order button, I got this error.
Edit; This is the error----- Error says; System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

any link that will be commented that are related to my post, will highly appreciated, Thank you so much.

Comment: Please do NOT post errors as images.  Where is Picker_OrderType defined in your code?  And please format your XAML so it is readable

Comment: I updated my post sir. Btw this is the error. Error says; System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.' 
and the Picker_OrderType is came from picker x:name, I already included it my UI design, that's how I code my UI.

Comment: The XAML you posted is for a different control

Comment: There are several problems with the XAML you did post.  1) `<x:String>` is not closed  2) you are using both `ItemsSource` and `<Picker.Items>` - you should pick one or the other, 3) you are using the same binding value for `ItemsSource` and `ItemDisplayBinding` - this cannot possibly be correct

Comment: 1. you can check how I code my design sir, thats the whole code in my picker. Please let know if its wrong. https://codeshare.io/kmRlnA
2. so which of the 2 sir should I use? that will fix my problem?
3. should I use itemsource sir or itemdisplaybinding?

Comment: hello sir,  I removed  the picker.item and I use only ItemDisplayBinding but still I got the same error.

Comment: You have already set the `ItemsSource ` for the Picker in the `OnAppearing()` method. So you do not need to set it in the picker again.

Comment: @Guangyu Bai, hello sir, https://codeshare.io/kmRlnA you can check here thats my updated UI design in my picker

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]